# Struggling with creating a function that stores user input to any chosen vector (using c++)

Tags: c++, vector

This is what I have so far...

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    vector<int> list1;
    vector<int> list2;

    void listAdd(int n, vector<int>v) {
while (n != 0) {
    v.push_back(n);
    cin >> n;
 }
 }

void printList(vector<int>v) {
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    cout << v[i] << " ";
} 
cout << endl;
}

int main() {
int nInput;

cout << "Please enter numbers for list1... (end with a '0') " << endl;
cin >> nInput;
listAdd(nInput, list1);
printList(list1);
         return 0;
    }
```

I basically want all numbers entered by the user (until they enter a 0) to be stored in the vector called list1. Then later i can call the same function to add numbers to another vector...

Help really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the vectors by reference

```
void listAdd(int n, vector<int>& v);

void printList(vector<int>& v);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! very much appreciated :)